# How to book a free rebooking flight in a multi flight segment with Lufthansa?

Tags: air-travel, tickets, lufthansa

I want to book three flights on the same ticket: Flight 1 from A to B, a couple of days later flight 2 from B to C and around two months later flight 3 from C back to A. I know the exact dates for flight 1 and 2, but I want to be able to rebook flight 3 if necessary.

Lufthansa offers Economy Flexible (instead of Economy restricted) tickets for exactly these cases that allow for free rebooking. However, I can't find a way to book such a Economy Flexible ticket only for flight 3, I have to do it for all 3 flights. What are my options?

Comment: Just to state the obvious upfront: A good travel agency will be able to assist you with such a booking.

Comment: Also, the question of how to book into specific fare classes is often discussed in frequent flyer forums (typically to maximize mileage earning, though). The common consensus seems to be that a "proper" travel agent is needed for such tasks, as travel booking websites typically lack this functionality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Mixed fare class bookings are generally not possible online**.  To be a little more precise, most engines will happily compose the cheapest tickets from mixed fare classes, but do not give you fine-grained control over individual segments.  See also [Pricing and booking mixed-class fares, with economy & premium economy combined?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34243/pricing-and-booking-mixed-class-fares-with-economy-premium-economy-combined), which is about essentially the same issue.

I'd generally recommend figuring out the exact flights/fare classes you want on [ITA Matrix](https://matrix.itasoftware.com/), and then:

1. Call the airline and book through them.  Will usually incur a booking fee.
2. Find a (good) travel agent and book through them.  Booking fees may apply, but will usually be less since they also get a commission from the airline.  Not all travel agents will be able to assist though.

Comment: For what it's worth KLM (and probably Air France and anyone else using the same booking engine) does let you do this on-line. As long as you force it into advanced mode by picking 'return to/from a different airport' or book a multi-city ticket. After the initial flight selection there's a way to expand the class and pick per segment -- I've done it several times. However a good travel agent is still the best bet -- although if you have frequent flyer status you may have a dedicated booking line that will waive the booking fee.

Comment: @SpaceDog The travel class (economy/business/etc), or the actual fare class?

Comment: If I recall you can change each segment between economy, economy flex and business. But not down to changing the actual letter fare code. I've done it because the flight I often take has very cheap business class outgoing but very expensive on the return leg (I've never worked out why). So I fly out business and back economy. But there is the option to pick flex in there as well.

Comment: Of course you have to be careful, because the initial search is prices all for one class, so you have to go back and forth a bit to check the differences. That's why a good travel agent would help, I just don't have access to one here (which might actually be a good question to ask on here sometime I get the chance).